# composer update error: requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.3

I tried to update my composer json file and got this error today any ideas?

composer error message:

```
PS F:\xampp\htdocs\theatre> composer update
```

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.4.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.19

```
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.18
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.17
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.16
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.15
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.14
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.13
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.12
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.11
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.10
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.9
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.8
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.7
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.6
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.5
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.4
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.3
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.2
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.1
- laracasts/presenter 0.1.0 requires illuminate/support 4.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
- laracasts/presenter 0.1.1 requires illuminate/support 4.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
- laracasts/presenter 0.1.2 requires illuminate/support 4.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
- laracasts/presenter 0.1.3 requires illuminate/support 4.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
- laracasts/presenter 0.1.4 requires illuminate/support ~4.1 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.1, v
```

4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9]. - laracasts/presenter 0.1.0 requires illuminate/support 4.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
    - laracasts/presenter 0.1.1 requires illuminate/support 4.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
    - laracasts/presenter 0.1.2 requires illuminate/support 4.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
    - laracasts/presenter 0.1.3 requires illuminate/support 4.1.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
    - laracasts/presenter 0.1.4 requires illuminate/support ~4.1 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.1, v
4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].

```
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.14|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.18|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.29|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.1.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- don't install illuminate/support v4.2.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
- Installation request for laravel/framework 5.4.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.0, v5.4.1, v5.4.10, v5.4.11, v5.4.12, v5.4.13, v5.4.14, v5.4.15, v5.4.16, v5.4.17, v5.4.18, v5.4.19, v5.4.2, v5.4.20, v5.4.21, v5.4.3, v5.4.4, v5.4.5, v5.4.6, v5.4.7, v5.4.8, v5.4.9].
- Installation request for laracasts/presenter 0.1.* -> satisfiable by laracasts/presenter[0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.1.4].
```

Here is the composer json:

```
{
"name": "laravel\/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "components/bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^2.4",
    "intervention/image": "^2.3",
    "larapack/voyager-hooks": "^0.1.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4",
    "tcg/voyager": "^0.11.9",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "^3.3",
    "laracasts/presenter": "0.1.*",
    "folklore/graphql": "~1.0.0"

},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "laracasts/generators": "^1.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "hooks"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app\/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests\/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
}
```

}

Comment: do you change the version of any package manually before running the update command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `"laracasts/presenter": "0.1.*"` should be changed to `"laracasts/presenter": "0.2.*"`. 
Here in changelog they say that Laravel 5 support is added in 0.2.0 version

Comment: That was it.  How did you pick up on that?

Comment: I remember that illuminate/support of version 4 was included into Laravel 4, so I've checked the the repo of laracasts/presenter on GitHub because it required those old version of illuminate/support and found that 0.1 is old version which was supported only by Laravel 4